# \addplot3 in pgfplots plots data beyond axis limits

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When using `pgfplots` for a 3D graph and reading the data from a table, is there a way to truncate the data at the *axis limits* specified in the `axis` environment ?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        width=16cm,height=8cm,
        view={-45}{65},
        scale only axis,
        xmin=200,xmax=500,
        xlabel={data1},
        ymin=0,ymax=80,
        ylabel={data2},
        zmin=0,zmax=1,
        zlabel={data3},
    ]
    \addplot3 table[row sep=crcr] {
            250 0 0\\
            250 25 0.2\\
            250 50 0.3\\
            250 75 0.2\\
            250 100 0\\
        };
    \addplot3 table[row sep=crcr] {
            450 0 0.5\\
            450 25 0.1\\
            450 50 0\\
            450 75 0.1\\
            450 100 0.5\\
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

In this example, the `ydata` of each table goes up to `100`, while the `ymax` value specified in the `axis` options is `80`. In this case, the output looks like:

[image: Output for MWE]

Note how the plotted lines go beyond the prescribed axis limits. Is there a way either to read the data up to a certain value (in this case `ymax`) or an option that can be specified in the `axis` environment to avoid displaying curves beyond axis limits ?

Comment: You can set `restrict y to domain=0:80`, but that will only filter out the points that exceed the axis limits, not clip the line at the limiting plane of the axis. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Jake That worked perfectly ! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter out the coordinates that fall outside the axis range by setting `restrict y to domain=0:80`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        width=16cm,height=8cm,
        view={-45}{65},
        scale only axis,
        xmin=200,xmax=500,
        xlabel={data1},
        ymin=0,ymax=80, restrict y to domain=0:80,
        ylabel={data2},
        zmin=0,zmax=1,
        zlabel={data3},
    ]
    \addplot3 table[row sep=crcr] {
            250 0 0\\
            250 25 0.2\\
            250 50 0.3\\
            250 75 0.2\\
            250 100 0\\
        };
    \addplot3 table[row sep=crcr] {
            450 0 0.5\\
            450 25 0.1\\
            450 50 0\\
            450 75 0.1\\
            450 100 0.5\\
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```